# OpenCL Java bindings for android

Tags: java, android, binding, opencl

I am working in Java technology since 2010. So I am not use to C/C++ languages. Recently I need to use OpenCL for Java and android. There are many bindings of Java for OpenCL are available like JavaCL, oCL etc. JavaCL is based on JNA. Android does not support JNA. So is there any way to use these bindings with android. Or is there any bindings of OpenCL specifically for Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official support for OpenCL in Android. They went so far as to remove the unofficial OpenCL drivers from Nexus 10:

http://www.anandtech.com/show/7191/android-43-update-for-nexus-10-and-4-removes-unofficial-opencl-drivers

The reason for the removal was quite likely political, as they (Google) want everyone to use their own renderscript with android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html

It shouldn't be too much of an hassle to port existing OpenCL kernels into a renderscript kernels. I have no actual experience on the peformance but it should, at least eventually, be pretty much the same as simply using OpenCL directly.

Comment: With bad luck you might have kernels, which are impossible to port efficiently to Render Script whose programming model is more limited. http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2013-08-01/google-blocked-opencl-on-android-4-3/